# jQuery ajax call is executing twice sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I saw that there are other questions similar to this, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

I have an ajax call that should insert some data into MySQL database, but sometimes, data is inserted twice. It doesn't happen all the time. Only sometimes. And it seems to happen with random users.

I didn't find elements with duplicateds Id's. It looks like the script is not loading twice, as it isn't happening all the time.

This JS script is been loaded inside a Bootstrap Modal:

```
<script src="js/app/lancamentos/vendas/venda.js"></script>
```

Here's my ajax call, inside function cadastrar():

```
//Define método a ser utilizado ao enviar formulário
        var classe = "Venda";
        var metodo = "cadastrar";

        //Define url
        //Esse valor é utilizado para definição de permissão dentro da classe PHP
        var url = "cadastra-venda";

        //Habilita campos de valores totais
        $('#valorTotalProdutos, #valorTotalDesconto, #valorTotalCredito, #valorTotalVenda').prop('disabled', false);

        //Dados do formulário
        var formData = new FormData($('#formCadastro')[0]);
        var idVenda = $("#formCadastro #idVenda").val();
        var idCliente = $("#formCadastro #idCliente").val();

        //Informações adicionais do formulário
        formData.append('classe', classe);
        formData.append('metodo', metodo);
        formData.append('url', url);

        //Argumentos da função - Venda::cadastrar
        formData.append('arg[]', idVenda);
        formData.append('arg[]', idCliente);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'config/router.php',
            data: formData,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {

                //Preenche campos de empresa e depósito
                $("#formCadastro #idEmpresa").val($('#formCadastro #empresa').val());
                $("#formCadastro #idDeposito").val($('#formCadastro #deposito').val());

                //Coloca pedido de venda em modo Somente Leitura
                $("#formCadastro #somenteLeitura").val('S');
                verificarPermissao();

                $('body').loadingModal('destroy');
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('body').loadingModal('destroy');
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar o pedido de venda.');
            }
        });
```

Function verificarPermissao() inside success call only disable some inputs. Nothing more than that.

And here's how the ajax is called:

```
$("#buttonSalvarVenda").unbind().click(function () {
        cadastrar();
    });
```

That's how the button looks like:

```
<button type="button" id="buttonSalvarVenda" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: Is it a `submit` button? If so, you need to disable the default action.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem? If not... there's little hope we'll be able to.

Comment: @Barmar, it isn't a submit button. It's  just a button tag.

Comment: @KevinB, that's another problem. I can't recreate the problem in our test enviroment. And it doesn't happen with all users.

Comment: @KevinB, I'm sorry. I've updated my question with the answer.

Comment: BTW, `.unbind()` is deprecated, `.off()` is preferred. But that's not an answer to the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would duplicate the AJAX request, so something must be calling `cadastrar()` twice. Are you sure the user isn't clicking the button twice? Try disabling the button while the AJAX call is occurring, so they can't double-click.

Comment: @Barmar, after user clicks the button a Loading Modal appears to avoid that. Even so, I'll disable the button to see what happens.

Comment: Have you ever been able to reproduce this yourself, or just getting reports from random users?

Comment: @Barmar, just report from random users. I've tried to simulate the configuration from browser and OS, but no success.

Comment: Then it's going to be practically impossible for us to figure it out from this tiny snippet. I think I've exhausted my list of common causes of duplicate requests. You could try adding some console logging, and asking users who run into the problem to send you their logs. But unless you have sophisticated users, that may be too much to ask.

Comment: @Barmar, I've placed some console.log() information inside js code to try to find out what is happening. I'll monitore a user with this problem to see. I'll update here as soon as I have an answer.